# How to assign 0 to summation of a field if no entry exists for the group by field in teradata SQL query result

Tags: sql, teradata

I have below query which is used for getting summation of an amount column but as you can see also in the attached screenshot that, there's no entry for NATURAL PERSON for Corporates as there aren't any entry in the table for NATURAL PERSON for CUST_TYPE=Corporates. Please suggest how to get NATURAL PERSON row also for Coporates with 0 assigned against it. *Searched for similar questions but didn't get the result with provided suggestions*

```
SELECT CUST_TYPE,FINAL_SME_CATEGORY, SUM(CUST_COMPENSATABLE_AMT) AS TOTAL_SUM FROM  ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL_SCV WHERE FINAL_SME_CATEGORY IN ('SMALL','NATURAL PERSON') GROUP BY 1,2 ORDER BY 1,2;
```

[image: NATURAL PERSON]

I tried few queries with ZEROIFNULL, NVL, COALESCE but all of them also gave the same result. Even tried writing CASE statements still didn't get the desired result.

```
SELECT CUST_TYPE,FINAL_SME_CATEGORY, COALESCE(SUM(CUST_COMPENSATABLE_AMT), 0) AS TOTAL_SUM FROM  ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL_SCV WHERE FINAL_SME_CATEGORY IN ('SMALL','NATURAL PERSON') GROUP BY 1,2 ORDER BY 1,2;

SELECT CUST_TYPE,FINAL_SME_CATEGORY, ZEROIFNULL(SUM(CUST_COMPENSATABLE_AMT)) AS TOTAL_SUM FROM  ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL_SCV WHERE FINAL_SME_CATEGORY IN ('SMALL','NATURAL PERSON') GROUP BY 1,2 ORDER BY 1,2;

SELECT CUST_TYPE,FINAL_SME_CATEGORY, NVL(SUM(CUST_COMPENSATABLE_AMT),0) AS TOTAL_SUM FROM  ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL_SCV WHERE FINAL_SME_CATEGORY IN ('SMALL','NATURAL PERSON') GROUP BY 1,2 ORDER BY 1,2;

SELECT CUST_TYPE, FINAL_SME_CATEGORY, CASE WHEN SUM(CUST_COMPENSATABLE_AMT)=0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(CUST_COMPENSATABLE_AMT) END AS TOTAL_SUM FROM  ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL_SCV WHERE FINAL_SME_CATEGORY IN ('SMALL','NATURAL PERSON') GROUP BY 1,2 ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Answer (score 0):

first do cross join cust_type and final_sme_catgory.

```
select distinct cust_type from table cross join
(select distinct final_sme_catgory from table) temp.
```

After that left join with your group by query and join with cust_type and final_sme_catgory . use nvl function to display total_sum or 0 value.
sample query:

```
with cte cross_table (
 select distinct cust_type from table cross join
    (select distinct final_sme_catgory from table) temp.
),
group_by_result(
--
select cust_type ,final_sme_catgory,sum(value) as total from table group by ust_type ,final_sme_catgory),

select cte.cust_type ,cte.final_sme_catgory,nvl(r.total ,0) as total
from cross_table cte left join group_by_result r on cte.cust_type =r.cust_type 
and cte.final_sme_catgory=r.final_sme_catgory
```

Comment: I didn't understood ```group_by_result(
--
select cust_type ,final_sme_catgory,sum(value) as total from table group by ust_type ,final_sme_catgory)```

Comment: Also, what is group_by_result(....)? It is used in a LEFT JOIN with CTE defined before it so it has to be a temp table but I don't recognize that format .... Is it new to teradata?

Comment: group_by_result , and cross_table  are common table expression.. (CTE) in postgresql,mysql and oracle

Comment: Get the logic and convert into teradata. I think teradata should support CTE (https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-VantageTM-SQL-Data-Manipulation-Language/March-2019/Select-Statements/WITH-Modifier/Examples/Example-Common-Table-Expression)

Comment: *group_by_result* is just another CTE. Teradata supports NVL, bt you better switch NVL to Standard SQL COALESCE

Comment: Ohh couldn't figure out the second CTE due to unclear indentation maybe.... anyway..... 
cte.final_sme_catgory=r.final_sme_catgory isn't working since the first CTE i.e., cross_table doesn't have the field final_sme_catgory and hence query isn't running

Comment: Below query gave the same result as pasted in question above.
```WITH TEMP1 AS
(
 SELECT DISTINCT CUST_TYPE FROM ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL_SCV 
 CROSS JOIN
 (SELECT DISTINCT FINAL_SME_CATEGORY FROM ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL_SCV) T1
),
TEMP2 AS
(
 SELECT CUST_TYPE, FINAL_SME_CATEGORY, SUM(CUST_COMPENSATABLE_AMT) AS TOTAL FROM ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL_SCV WHERE FINAL_SME_CATEGORY IN ('SMALL','NATURAL PERSON') GROUP BY CUST_TYPE, FINAL_SME_CATEGORY
)
SELECT A.CUST_TYPE, B.FINAL_SME_CATEGORY, COALESCE(B.TOTAL ,0) AS TOTAL
FROM TEMP1 A LEFT JOIN TEMP2 B 
ON A.CUST_TYPE=B.CUST_TYPE;```

Comment: Please accept the answer and upvote if you get the result out of it

Comment: The result is same as the screenshot i have posted in question..... It's not working......
cte.final_sme_catgory=r.final_sme_catgory isn't working since the first CTE i.e., cross_table doesn't have the field final_sme_catgory